# Mongoose model generation from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

When building an API to connect to MongoDB using mongoose, is there a way to generate all of the necessary code and schema from a JSON data blob? I have a payload I'm fetching from a third-party API that I want to store in the database.  The JSON array I get has 15-20 fields, so its a bit of code that I'd rather generate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598252/initialize-mongoose-schema-from-json